# Power Query M filter for import Data

Tags: filter, powerbi, powerquery, m

Im trying to import a dataset on Power Query, but I need to filter this Data with values before 10/1/2021, someone knows how I can filter this? I didnt find it in M documentation.

Tks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Filters are on the column header dropdown menu:

[image]

Or right-click on a cell to apply filters.

[image]

Comment: Sorry man, maybe i need to make my self clear. 
I cant import the Data because its big, so i need to make the filter on the query editor to filter before import

Comment: That's what this does.  The data you see in the Power Query editor is only a sample.  Import only happens after you "Close & Apply".  Then the M query is (partially) folded into the source SQL and executed.